# No module named 'PyCRC'

Tags: python, manifest.json

I want tou use `ECGRecord` package which I installed it using pip.
but when I run my code it says `No module named 'PyCRC'` despite I installed both pycrc and ECGRecord.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyecg\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pyecg.dataset import RecordTicket, ECGDataset
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyecg\dataset.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ishneholterlib import Holter
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\ishneholterlib\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from PyCRC.CRCCCITT import CRCCCITT
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyCRC'
```

when I searched for solving this issue, I found [this](https://github.com/mairas/hysen/issues/26) solution on GitHub:

fixed by changing manifest.json:

```
{
"domain": "hysen",
"name": "Hysen Thermostat Controller",
"documentation": "",
"requirements": ["broadlink==0.13.0", "pythoncrc"],
"dependencies": [
"http"
],
"codeowners": ["@MarkCarter", "@iwantto.com"]
}
```

but I don't know what is "manifest.json" and where can I find it. How can I solve this issue?

I want to open a [database](https://physionet.org/content/nsr2db/1.0.0/) with *.ecg format:

```
from pyecg import ECGRecord


# To load a ishine formatted ECG record
hea_path = "/path/to/your/ecg/file"
record = ECGRecord.from_ishine(hea_path)
```

Comment: have you tried pip install pythoncrc

Comment: yes but I still have the same error.

Comment: can you share your code too where you have the import error?

Comment: I edited my question and shared my code, I want to load an "ishine" formatted database.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a stacktrace of the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you found on GitHub isn't related to your case - hence why you couldn't find the `manifest.json` file. It just so happened that a possible error with that library was the same error you're having here - `No module named PyCRC`. [There's an open issue on the pyECG repo with this exact problem.](https://github.com/taoyilee/pyECG/issues/3) The solution there is to simply `pip install pythoncrc`. If you've already tried this, I would make sure you are installing it to the right location - for example, if you're using a venv to run your code I'd make sure the package is being installed in the venv.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/taoyilee/pyECG/issues/3#issuecomment-866048577
Solution is thanks to carlosperezm:

Commit 95f854c introduced a fix, but it was not pushed to Pypi.
What worked for me was:

```
pip uninstall PyCRC
pip install pythoncrc
```

Comment: Please format your code properly, [click here to learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).